# MS Teams bot chat is hidden

Tags: .net, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have created MS Teamsbot with 2 functionality : 1- display proactive messages after request on my API. 2 display duplicate of my message - that I sent in chat. Hosting on Azure - in test chat all working fine.Proactive messages working fine in MS Teams. After my request on API it send message to my bot.

The issue that the chat with my bot is hidden. When I install it, I can see the chat for a second
[image: bot chat exist on first two seconds] and then it [image: disappear]. Each time when I reinstall bot, chat appear for a second and then disappear.

Bot ID - e0dc7704-ffdf-47db-8e8e-3bdfd4d1db32

Comment: Perhaps send some code so we can see what's going on. There's no obvious reason why this is happening, but perhaps instead of posting a message you're updating or removing / deleting one, for example.

Comment: Could you please check isNotificationOnly flag is set to false for your bot configuration in your app manifest?

Comment: ...do you have a chat in your teams client that is labeled 'Only Me'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isNotificationOnly flag was set to false